# How to send values to a postgres function?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a function with parameters of numerical type, I have done the query successfully, my problems is that I do not know how to pass several parameters within the IN, `where id in(parameter)`.
The id is of type `BIGINT`

From JAVA I have the following query:

```
select parametro1, parametro2, parametro3 from function_detalls ("parameters");
```

Where `parameters` is a string type `1,2,3,4,5,6,7, ....`

My question is how can I pass this type of parameter to the function?

Answer (score 2):

Pass an array to your function and use `WHERE = ANY()`.

For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func_test(params text[])
RETURNS SETOF test
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT * FROM test WHERE txt = ANY(params);
END;
$$
```

---

To call:

```
SELECT * FROM func_test(ARRAY['hello', 'world']);
```

---

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e72K9ZkHCz5GyF9eiAAC1u/0) to show it in action

Comment: @J Spratt I lost a bit in your answer, the parameters to send is always volatile, that is, the size varies, as I do with an array of 1000?